# Publish Off-Chain Item with On-Chain "notes"

Tags: blockchain

I was reading the "publish" description in the JSON-RPC API and I had a doubt about the possibility of my application. I needed to publish an off-chain item with some metadata information embedded on-chain.

For example: "iPhone 2018, New, $400" on the blockchain while {picture.jpg} goes off-chain, but they are still "together".

Comment: Your best bet here is to publish two stream items simultaneously in a single transaction – one off-chain and one on-chain. You can have the both in the same stream, or in two different streams. These two items will be naturally associated with each other since they will have the same transaction ID. See the **publishmulti** API (in MultiChain 2.0) for making this easy.

Comment: I wanted to disable publishing more than one item per transaction, since I wanted to charge a fixed fee for stream publishing, but I guess I'll do it using stream filters.

Is it possible to have a filter that on publishmulti that forces the user to publish those two streams, one on-chain and one off-chain?

If not, could you point me somewhere in the source code that could guide me to the respective functions?

Comment: You would do this as a transaction filter, not a stream filter, since a stream filter only works on the level of a single stream item. Inside the transaction filter all the information you need will be returned by the getfiltertransaction() callback. If you use testtxfilter (or the Web Demo) you can see the response of this callback for the different situations.

Answer (score 0):

It is feasible to have on-chain entries refer to physical assets or pictures off-chain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ERC721 standard to create a non-fungible token for each of the item.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

        /// @title ERC-721 Non-Fungible Token Standard
        /// @dev See https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md
        ///  Note: the ERC-165 identifier for this interface is 0x80ac58cd
        interface ERC721 /* is ERC165 */ {
            /// @dev This emits when ownership of any NFT changes by any mechanism.
            ///  This event emits when NFTs are created (`from` == 0) and destroyed
            ///  (`to` == 0). Exception: during contract creation, any number of NFTs
            ///  may be created and assigned without emitting Transfer. At the time of
            ///  any transfer, the approved address for that NFT (if any) is reset to none.
            event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 indexed _tokenId);

            /// @dev This emits when the approved address for an NFT is changed or
            ///  reaffirmed. The zero address indicates there is no approved address.
            ///  When a Transfer event emits, this also indicates that the approved
            ///  address for that NFT (if any) is reset to none.
            event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _approved, uint256 indexed _tokenId);

            /// @dev This emits when an operator is enabled or disabled for an owner.
            ///  The operator can manage all NFTs of the owner.
            event ApprovalForAll(address indexed _owner, address indexed _operator, bool _approved);

            /// @notice Count all NFTs assigned to an owner
            /// @dev NFTs assigned to the zero address are considered invalid, and this
            ///  function throws for queries about the zero address.
            /// @param _owner An address for whom to query the balance
            /// @return The number of NFTs owned by `_owner`, possibly zero
            function balanceOf(address _owner) external view returns (uint256);

            /// @notice Find the owner of an NFT
            /// @dev NFTs assigned to zero address are considered invalid, and queries
            ///  about them do throw.
            /// @param _tokenId The identifier for an NFT
            /// @return The address of the owner of the NFT
            function ownerOf(uint256 _tokenId) external view returns (address);

            /// @notice Transfers the ownership of an NFT from one address to another address
            /// @dev Throws unless `msg.sender` is the current owner, an authorized
            ///  operator, or the approved address for this NFT. Throws if `_from` is
            ///  not the current owner. Throws if `_to` is the zero address. Throws if
            ///  `_tokenId` is not a valid NFT. When transfer is complete, this function
            ///  checks if `_to` is a smart contract (code size > 0). If so, it calls
            ///  `onERC721Received` on `_to` and throws if the return value is not
            ///  `bytes4(keccak256("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)"))`.
            /// @param _from The current owner of the NFT
            /// @param _to The new owner
            /// @param _tokenId The NFT to transfer
            /// @param data Additional data with no specified format, sent in call to `_to`
            function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId, bytes data) external payable;

            /// @notice Transfers the ownership of an NFT from one address to another address
            /// @dev This works identically to the other function with an extra data parameter,
            ///  except this function just sets data to ""
            /// @param _from The current owner of the NFT
            /// @param _to The new owner
            /// @param _tokenId The NFT to transfer
            function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external payable;

            /// @notice Transfer ownership of an NFT -- THE CALLER IS RESPONSIBLE
            ///  TO CONFIRM THAT `_to` IS CAPABLE OF RECEIVING NFTS OR ELSE
            ///  THEY MAY BE PERMANENTLY LOST
            /// @dev Throws unless `msg.sender` is the current owner, an authorized
            ///  operator, or the approved address for this NFT. Throws if `_from` is
            ///  not the current owner. Throws if `_to` is the zero address. Throws if
            ///  `_tokenId` is not a valid NFT.
            /// @param _from The current owner of the NFT
            /// @param _to The new owner
            /// @param _tokenId The NFT to transfer
            function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external payable;

            /// @notice Set or reaffirm the approved address for an NFT
            /// @dev The zero address indicates there is no approved address.
            /// @dev Throws unless `msg.sender` is the current NFT owner, or an authorized
            ///  operator of the current owner.
            /// @param _approved The new approved NFT controller
            /// @param _tokenId The NFT to approve
            function approve(address _approved, uint256 _tokenId) external payable;

            /// @notice Enable or disable approval for a third party ("operator") to manage
            ///  all of `msg.sender`'s assets.
            /// @dev Emits the ApprovalForAll event. The contract MUST allow
            ///  multiple operators per owner.
            /// @param _operator Address to add to the set of authorized operators.
            /// @param _approved True if the operator is approved, false to revoke approval
            function setApprovalForAll(address _operator, bool _approved) external;

            /// @notice Get the approved address for a single NFT
            /// @dev Throws if `_tokenId` is not a valid NFT
            /// @param _tokenId The NFT to find the approved address for
            /// @return The approved address for this NFT, or the zero address if there is none
            function getApproved(uint256 _tokenId) external view returns (address);

            /// @notice Query if an address is an authorized operator for another address
            /// @param _owner The address that owns the NFTs
            /// @param _operator The address that acts on behalf of the owner
            /// @return True if `_operator` is an approved operator for `_owner`, false otherwise
            function isApprovedForAll(address _owner, address _operator) external view returns (bool);
        }

        interface ERC165 {
            /// @notice Query if a contract implements an interface
            /// @param interfaceID The interface identifier, as specified in ERC-165
            /// @dev Interface identification is specified in ERC-165. This function
            ///  uses less than 30,000 gas.
            /// @return `true` if the contract implements `interfaceID` and
            ///  `interfaceID` is not 0xffffffff, `false` otherwise
            function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceID) external view returns (bool);
        }

        interface ERC721TokenReceiver {
            /// @notice Handle the receipt of an NFT
            /// @dev The ERC721 smart contract calls this function on the
            /// recipient after a `transfer`. This function MAY throw to revert and reject the transfer. Return
            /// of other than the magic value MUST result in the transaction being reverted.
            /// @notice The contract address is always the message sender.
            /// @param _operator The address which called `safeTransferFrom` function
            /// @param _from The address which previously owned the token
            /// @param _tokenId The NFT identifier which is being transferred
            /// @param _data Additional data with no specified format
            /// @return `bytes4(keccak256("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)"))`
            /// unless throwing
            function onERC721Received(address _operator, address _from, uint256 _tokenId, bytes _data) external returns(bytes4);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use emerNVS, [see the doc](http://emercoin.com/en/documentation/blockchain-services/emernvs).
This is like to blockchain-based distribute file system, when only owner can "modify" his file, and for all other file is read-only.
You can upload any arbitrary data up to 20K into blockchain for very low fee, less than $0.01 right now.
Picture you can keep off-chain, and withing NVS-file keep URL to a picture.